# Это атака на сервер? Что делать? Как выкрутится?

Tags: sql, wordpress, apache, ddos

Всем привет.

У меня виртуальный сервер на Ubuntu 14 (Nginx+Apache+MySql) Сайты на WordPress

В error.log сервера apache появляется такая хрень. После, чего сервер становится перегруженым и падает.

Объясните новичку что это такое?
Я на гуглил, что это атака в ввиде SQL -инъекции. Это так? Как с этим бороться?

Буду Вам благодарен за любой совет?

```
[Mon Dec 19 10:43:17.992197 2016] [:error] [pid 25428] [client 37.232.180.93:40030] \xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd1\x85 WordPress \xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb1\xd0\xba\xd1\x83 Lost connection to MySQL server during query \xd0\xb2 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81 SELECT * FROM my_posts WHERE ID = 245 LIMIT 1, \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, twentytwelve_content_width, is_page_template, get_page_template_slug, get_post, WP_Post::get_instance
[Mon Dec 19 10:43:17.992445 2016] [:error] [pid 29003] [client 46.163.173.103:40111] \xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd1\x85 WordPress \xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb1\xd0\xba\xd1\x83 Lost connection to MySQL server during query \xd0\xb2 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81 SELECT DISTINCT(label) FROM my_wp_rp_tags WHERE post_id=14549 ORDER BY weight desc;, \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/iconic-one/single.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/iconic-one/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, wp_rp_head_resources
```

Comment: При чём тут ddos? `[Mon Dec 19 10:43:17.992445 2016] [:error] [pid 29003] [client 46.163.173.103:40111] База данных WordPress возвратила ошибку Lost connection to MySQL server during query в ответ на запрос SELECT DISTINCT(label) FROM my_wp_rp_tags WHERE post_id=14549 ORDER BY weight desc;, выполненный require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/iconic-one/single.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/iconic-one/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, wp_rp_head_resources`

Comment: то, что ты показал - следствие какой-то проблемы. посмотри статистику соединений, смотри лимиты бд, вордпресса. кешируй ответы на nginx.

Comment: Смотрел логи syslog. И понял, что это не инъекция. Нашел такую закономерность. Если в 6:30 утра возникли такие ошибки. То MySQL умирает или сервер становится недоступным. Если же таких ошибок не было. То сервер работает без проблем.  Dec 16 06:30:33 slovarik kernel: [68362.962956] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] abort
Dec 16 06:30:33 slovarik kernel: [68362.962988] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] abort
Dec 16 06:30:33 slovarik kernel: [68362.963027] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] abort

Comment: скорее всего нужно руководствоваться вот этим советом https://communities.vmware.com/message/1757171

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это просто перекодировка русских символов.
Вот оригинал

```
Mon Dec 19 10:43:17.992197 2016] [:error] [pid 25428] [client 37.232.180.93:40030] База данных WordPress возвратила ошибку Lost connection to MySQL server during query в ответ на запрос SELECT * FROM my_posts WHERE ID = 245 LIMIT 1, выполненный require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, twentytwelve_content_width, is_page_template, get_page_template_slug, get_post, WP_Post::get_instance[Mon Dec 19 10:43:17.992445 2016] [:error] [pid 29003] [client 46.163.173.103:40111] База данных WordPress возвратила ошибку Lost connection to MySQL server during query в ответ на запрос SELECT DISTINCT(label) FROM my_wp_rp_tags WHERE post_id=14549 ORDER BY weight desc;, выполненный require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/iconic-one/single.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/iconic-one/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, wp_rp_head_resources
```

Просто обрыв соединения с БД. Возможно нехватка ресурсов.